# How to use jstl el to call a dynamic nested property

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

if you wanna call the getter method from a specific bean using a dynamic key you use like that:

```
${bean[getterName]}
```

but if you wanna call double nested, or triple nested properties with a dynamic name how does it works, is it possible?

```
${bean.propertyA.propertyB} WORKS
${bean[propertyA.propertyB]} DOES NOT WORKS
<c:set var="dynamicKey" value="propertyA.propertyB" />
${bean[dynamicKey]} DOES NOT WORKS
```

UPDATE:

For now we're handling like that:

```
<c:forTokens items="${property}" delims="." var="item">   
    <c:set var="value" value="${value[item]}" />
</c:forTokens>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 years we are leaving like this since it does not seems to have a big impact on performance.

`<c:forTokens items="${property}" delims="." var="item">
      <c:set var="value" value="${value[item]}" />
</c:forTokens>`

Answer (score 1):

Dot notation vs brackets notation with nested properties:

```
${bean.propertyA.propertyB}
${bean[propertyA.propertyB]} ==> Not right, instead
${bean["propertyA"]["propertyB"]}
```

Your example with JSTL:

```
<c:set var="dynamicKey" value="${bean['propertyA']['propertyB']}" />
<c:out value="${dynamicKey}" />
```